# Visual Studio Code - Automatic exclude based on .gitignore

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

I'd like VSCode to automatically exclude files/folders based on my `.gitignore` configuration.

For the explorer exclusion I've found an extension (`explorer-excluded-files` which manages the `files.exclude` setting), but for the quick open file (`cmd + p`) I didn't find anything.

I guess I can try and tweak other `*.exclude` settings but I wonder why isn't there a global method to exclude `.gitignore` entries in all relevant places? Otherwise I have to manually sync the settings every time `.gitignore` changes.

Comment: opposite question is [here](/q/42891463/11107541).  intentionally not closing as duplicate right now because it's not clear to me whether/how exclude and ignore settings can override one another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding the explorer, in addition of the existing plugin you have found, there is a request in progress: [`Microsoft/vscode` issue 38878](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38878)

But regarding Quick Open, [issue 41495](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41495) includes the comment:

> Are those files covered by a gitignore pattern?
> It now skips gitignored files by default.
> You can disable this with "`search.useIgnoreFiles`": false if you prefer.

So are you using (with a current 2018 version of VSCode) the setting `search.useIgnoreFiles`?

---

Four years later (VSCode 1.68, May 2022), this issue is fixed with [PR 149967](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/149967/commits/356d1e744062c2a457b5ad40a8f24c8512578dd0) and the new setting `explorer.excludeGitIgnore`

> Controls whether entries in `.gitignore` should be parsed and excluded from the explorer.
> Similar to `files.exclude`.

[PR 150848](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/150848) mentions:

> Since this setting only applies to the explorer it is being renamed from `files.excludeGitIgnore` to `explorer.excludeGitIgnore`.

Comment: Not working for me. I have the setting on but I still see ignored files in the search.

Comment: @leonheess But [did you removed those ignored files from the index first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43511646/6309)? Meaning, those files might be currently tracked, in which case they would bot be impacted by a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I realized I'm facing this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26574

Comment: @leonheess Interesting. I will be monitoring this issue.